# "A loathsome feature of the crime"

Tags: word-usage

For the english native's speaker's perspective, would the usage of the word **loathsome** suit the context of this sentence. Or it does not suit at all.

> A **loathsome** feature of the crime was its commission while the victims were at prayer in the temple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only really speak from the perspective of the United States midwest, but to me, "loathsome" feels like the wrong word here. I want to explain why, but I'm having a hard time coming up with anything more than 'it feels wrong'.

I would suggest **egregious** instead.

Comment: Perhaps because it suggests some disgusting creature rather than a shocking crime.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think I'd be thrown off if somebody referred to a "loathsome crime".